# What are good multiclass options for a 6th-level cleric wanting to help in the front line?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, multi-classing, paladin, fighter

Last session my group and I reached 6th level. As a cleric of the Life Domain, I got access to all the class features that I wanted out of being a cleric. Now I seek to branch out to being more effective as a damage dealer, seeing as how we only have a rogue fighting in the front line.

I know multiclassing into fighter would be the most helpful out of every melee class, but I thought maybe going paladin will be better for me specifically seeing that I have the Channel Divinity feature twice per short rest now. Also it's important to note that I have only a score of 13 in Strength, and I'm heavily relying on the DM to hand me out a magic item that will help me with that as soon as I'll pick a melee class in the next level.
My overall stats are Strength 13, Dexterity 10, Constitution 14, Intelligence 10, Wisdom 18, Charisma 12.

So what would be more effective, a Fighter, or a Paladin?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. The title as currently phrased seems a little broad/opinion-based, but if you want to focus on optimizing for maximum damage per round (as suggested by the body), that seems more answerable to me. Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: It might help to know all your ability scores. I would assume your dexterity is even lower than your strength, or you would have mentioned it, but it would better if we knew for sure. Also, knowing your stats is essential for knowing which classes you are able to multiclass into.

Comment: Note that Cleric isn't necessarily a bad melee class!  Inflict Wounds is pretty badass.

Comment: If you are a cleric of life domain with access to heavy armor then why is your rogue the only one fighting on the front line?  Heavy armor and a shield with the ability to heal yourself makes you a very solid front line "tank."   You should be holding the front line and doing everything to get the attention of the bad guys so the rogue can hit them with surprise attacks.

Answer (score 6):

With your current ability scores, there are only a few classes for which you meet the [the Multiclassing prerequisites](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Prerequisites) (see chapter 6 of the Basic Rules or Player's Handbook).

You currently have 13 or more in Str, Con and Wis. That means you are eligible to multiclass in or out of only Barbarian, Cleric, Druid and Fighter. Barbarian would be a bad choice for a spell caster, so Fighter and Druid are your only current options. Since you're probably already tankier than a Druid would be (since they can't wear metal armor), that's probably not an upgrade either, though since druids are full casters, it would let you keep up your spell slot levels. If you want to become a Paladin, you'll need to increase your Charisma to at least a 13 first. The easy way to do that would be to stick with Cleric to level 8 where you'll get an ability score increase (I'd put +1 in Str and +1 in Cha).

But I'd also consider sticking with Cleric even longer! With access to heavy armor and shields, you're already a tanky front-line fighter if you want to be. The higher level spells you'll become able to cast are likely to be more impactful than the small benefits you'd get from adding a fighting style or even getting extra attacks (which are five levels away at best). If you find you're not hitting often enough, consider using a spell like *Bless* to buff you (and the rest of the party) before engaging, or use spell attacks like Inflict Wounds that benefit from your Wisdom modifier rather than only swinging a sword.

Comment: Inflict Wounds doesn't benefit from Wisdom modifier, and uses spell slots.

Comment: @IVisiBombI: It's a melee spell attack, so it will use your spell casting attribute rather than Strength or Dexterity. Its true that it does use a spell slot, but as a single-classed cleric, you'll probably low-level slots to spare, though that does depend a bit on how many encounters you'll have between long rests.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot multiclass to Paladin right now because your Charisma is too low.  Paladin requires STR *and* CHA be at least 13.  You will have to take 2 more levels of cleric to get your ASI at level 8.  Give 1 point to strength to increase your attack and damage modifiers and give the other to Charisma so you meet the minimum skill requirements for multiclassing to paladin.

If you choose fighter then you still might choose to take 2 levels of cleric because that is a shorter path to your next ASI and increased STR.  Boosting STR is not the only consideration but it is a factor to keep in mind if you are focused on increasing your melee damage output.